# Search implementation on classified site

Tags: php, search, solr, nutch, web-search

I am presently working on a classified site which is developed in PHP. I want to implement two types of search in our site:

1. Search from our own site
2. Search the web.

I was about to implement Solr for the first search, but am not sure how to implement 'Search the web' search. So can you please provide me suggestions on that, I have come to know about Nutch crawler, but dont know if that is the right choice. www.scrubtheweb.com  is the sample site with the implementation of both kinds(search the web and site search) of search. I want to implement search exactly same as that of www.scrubtheweb.com .

So please provide me suggestions on that

Comment: "Search the web" is usually done by linking to one of the existing search engines. You don't really want to build a search engine, do you?

Comment: No, we dont want to build a new search engine

Answer (score 1):

Use Google's [Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/).

Or, simply redirect your users to Google:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: But this will show the result on google page .I need to show the search result on my site itseif like the search used in  [link]http://www.scrubtheweb.com/cgi-bin/search.cgi?q=test

Comment: No, I dont want to buid a new search engine at the same time we dont want to redirect our users to google. I have thought about google's custom search, but it had the wordings such as 'powered by google', I dont want that. It should be similar to search from our own site.

Comment: @Rose why do you want to imply that you search the whole web from your website? People expect Google to do that, so it won't look strange to 'em.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Yahoo BOSS api](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/) for web search if you are willing to pay, since it is a paid api. It is a great way to customize your search

For free APIs you can have a look at [programmableweb](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Search). Not sure whether there is a free web search API or not.

Comment: Will have a look on that, any free api's?

Comment: @Rose You can have a look at [programmableweb](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Search) for apis. They have all the apis listed at one place.